# JQuery Mobile : Radio Button Doesn't Reflect

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I've created the radio button for jQuery mobile, I already declare the variable and the value, but why is not reflect, can anybody help I tried many time with different code but still didn't work.

Here is live code

https://jsfiddle.net/h47Lfnbp

```
var type = "Contractor";
$('input[name=CustCat]').filter('[value=Contractor]').attr('checked', true);
```

Many thank ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/snj4heoz/

here you need to remove `ui-radio-off` class then ad `ui-radio-on` class.

```
var inputs = $('input[name=CustCat]');

inputs.filter('[value=' + type + ']').first().attr('checked', true).siblings('label').removeClass('ui-radio-off').addClass('ui-radio-on');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am also a noob son i cant totally understand your meanings.But i guess you can't select the radio button which you choose,try this.If i misunderstood you question,please let me knowXD

```
$("#Architect").change(function(){
         if ($(this).prop("checked")){
           alert("you choose Architect");
           $('input[name=CustCat]').filter('[value=Architect]').attr('checked', true);
         };
         if($(this).prop("checked")==false){
           alert("you cancel Architect");
           $('input[name=CustCat]').filter('[value=Architect]').attr('checked', false);
         }
       });
```

and your `$("#ul-CustTypeDisplay").enhanceWithin();`show error,so i turn it into comment,and it really works.

Comment: The scenario is actually like this, on load the code will read on the variable of type which is "Contractor" or can be any value. So than it will filter the value and match which one it should checked. Is it clear, anyway thank you for the answer

Comment: so you only want the radio box to be checked? then i think your code is correct! What do you mean:"why is not reflect"?Sorry i'm Taiwanese, english is poor XD, maybe you didn't link the correct JQuery or etc. Did you check your console? Is there any error? Or i just post the whole file to you?